# Series expansion of Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}$ for $x>0$.
I want to prove that for $x> 0$, we have this series expansion.
$$\Gamma(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{n+x}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n,$$
where $$c_n=\frac{1}{n!}\int_1^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^n.$$

For the proof, I separated the integral

$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt=\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt+\int_1^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt.$$

At the first integral I used the taylor expansion of $e^{-t}$ and arrived to the desired term 
$$\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{x-1}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{n+x}.$$
For the second integral
$$I_2(x)=\int_1^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$$
I noticed that $I_2\in C^{\infty}(0,\infty)$ and that

$$I_2^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} t^{x-1} (\log t)^n dt,$$

and then, **expanded it in series**:

$$I_2(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{I_2^{(n)}(0) x^n}{n!}.$$

which is equivalent to the result.

But I am not convinced, because I can't just justify the differentiability of $I_2(x)$ at $x=0$, and then this series expansion, since I haven't even defined $I_2(x)$ for $x=0$.

How can I justify that last step?

Comment: good thing  you only needed to prove it for $x>0$

Comment: See the [Mittag-Leffler's Expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10.E24). First, use it with $\mathrm{f}\left(z\right) = \Gamma\left(1 + z\right) - 1 =  z\Gamma\left(z\right) - 1$ such that $ \Gamma\left(z\right) = {1 + \mathrm{f}\left(z\right) \over z}$.